# Can we always construct a category only based on the datas of an object in a given category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

As we can construct a category of categories or functors, by just setting categories(functors) as objects and functors(natural transformations) as morphisms. I wonder if we can always construct a category based on the datas of an object in a given category,and with some additional informations,such as morphisms,compositions,and so on.Indeed,those informations should satisfy the axioms of category.

this saying is right when we consider the category Grp.for example , we can define a category whose object is a single # , with morphisms elements of a fix group H in Grp, the composition law is defined to be group multiplication.

Comment: It is very special that groups can be realized as a kind of category. For most objects of most categories, there is no way to view the objects themselves as a category. That said, people have made a cottage industry of trying to "categorify" pre-existing structures in order to make them look like categories. The fact that categorifying a group doesn't change it is far from common, though.

Comment: Note that you can define a category with only one object and one arrow, and that object can be absolutely anything; so in a sense the answer to your question is yes, but in a boring way.